# How can I get these 2 SQL queries to return 1 result set? (They select the same items, with different where clauses)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge this queries into only one, to return 2 values ("scount_atp" where estado=1 and "scount_xxx" where estado=4) by date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha),"%m-%d-%Y") as sdate, COUNT(id) as scount_atp FROM entradas WHERE estado = '1' AND fecha <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AND fecha >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) GROUP BY sdate

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha),"%m-%d-%Y") as sdate, COUNT(id) as scount_xxx FROM entradas WHERE estado = '4' AND fecha <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AND fecha >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) GROUP BY sdate
```

I'm a newbie at MySQL, so I'm sorry if this is too basic...

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: You could use a case statement to select the different value based on what estado is. I'm not quite sure how to do this in MySQL though.

Comment: So, how the query would look like?

Comment: In MSSQL the query would be like select case estado when 1 then scount_atp when 4 scout_xxx end from entradas where estado in (1,4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha),"%m-%d-%Y") as sdate, 
  SUM(IF(estado = '1',1,0)) as scount_atp,
  SUM(IF(estado = '4',1,0)) as scount_xxx
FROM entradas 
WHERE estado IN('1','4')
  AND fecha <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) 
  AND fecha >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
GROUP BY sdate
```

Let me add an unrelated thing here: if the `estado` column is of type `INT`, you might want to write `1` instead of `'1'` - or you might up ending with a full table scan converting the int column to a string for comparison.

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the comma after scount_xxx but works great!

Comment: @EugenRieck Also with `fecha between ...`.

Comment: Great! One more question, do you know how could ir ORDER BY the sdate? Edited: Nevermind: I just reformated the "%m-%d-Y%"

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar in the past, this has worked for me:

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha),"%m-%d-%Y") as sdate, 
   COUNT(IF(estado = '1', 1, NULL)) as scount_atp, 
   COUNT(IF(estado = '4', 1, NULL)) as scount_xxx 
FROM entradas 
WHERE 
   fecha <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) 
   AND 
   fecha >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
GROUP BY sdate
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great too... Do you know how to ORDER BY the sdate? Edited: Nevermind: I just reformated the "%m-%d-Y%"